# Incorrect logic in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code in C++:

(where `arr.data[i-1] = 20; arr.date[i] = 30; payload = 50;`)

```
if (i > 0 && arr.data[i-1] < payload < arr.data[i]) {
    cout << arr.data[i-1] << " < " << payload << " < " << arr.data[i] << "\n";
}
```

and I am getting the statement returned as

```
20 < 50 < 30
```

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Use a compiler with warnings enabled! See [Coliru example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f02d1c30f9b7b3f).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't chain comparison operators like this:

```
if (i > 0 && arr.data[i-1] < payload < arr.data[i]) {
```

Instead, it should look like this:

```
if (i > 0 && arr.data[i-1] < payload && payload < arr.data[i]) {
```

Note that you do this in a few places in your code.

Comment: Thank you! I was coming from other languages where you can string the comparisons together.

Comment: @Ben: "a<b<c" will evaluate "a<b" alone first, and this results either in "true<c" or in "false<c". Neither of them is what you want.

Comment: There's only one language I've heard of that allows chaining comparisons like that. Most won't accept that

Answer (score 1):

Relational operators in C++ are left associative, so this is how the implementation reads it:

(i > 0 && arr.data[i-1] < payload) = **TRUE = 1** (Boolean logic)

so,
(**1** < arr.data[i]) = **TRUE**